# customising pdoc automatically generated documentation for python

Tags: python, html, documentation, documentation-generation, pdoc

I used pdoc3 to automatically generate documentation from the docstrings at the beginning of each python class/function by executing the following

`pdoc3 --html ambit_stochastics`
The resulting documentation can be found at https://danleonte.github.io/Ambit_Stochastics/index.html

1. Can I remove the `ambit_stochastics` from `ambit_stochastics.helpers` on the index page and, subsequently, on all of the subpages? It seems unnecessary and wordy.
2. Can I edit the index page ( the one that pops up when accessing the link) to add some introductory text? how about other templates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your #1 point without editing the template, but you can tackle #2 by including a module docstring in your `ambit_stochastics/__init__.py` [like pdoc does](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/4aa70de2221a34a3003a7e5f52a9b91965f0e359/pdoc/__init__.py#L1-L9). This ten renders on the main module page, along with its TOC for titles:
https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/